# TypeError undefined is not an object (evaluating 'value.replace')

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

The strange thing is that it works on my web browser when I run it on Firefox using the Metro Bundler, but when I try to do it on an Android phone I get the error: TypeError undefined is not an object (evaluating 'value.replace')

```
const setMyString = (value) => {
    let string = value.replace(/\D/g,' ');
    setString(string);
}
```

It seems that this function sets the error.

```
const [myString, setString] = useState('');

<Input   
    value={myString}
    onChange={e => setMyString(e.target.value)} />
```

Here's the rest of the relevant code. The error happens when I use the virtual keyboard and enter a number.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the value of `e.target` on your Android phone? From the error, it seems `val` is undefined in `setMyString` which implies `e.target.value` is `undefined` which means `value` doesn't exist on `e.target`. So I would suggest figuring out what `e.target` is and why it doesn't contain a `value`?

Comment: e.target, isn't that the input field? Is it different on Android? Because it works fine on my web browser (Firefox). Also, when I debug, should I debug it on Firefox, because I don't know how to debug on an Android phone.